# Как в VS code включить отображение автора кода для каждой строки?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Как-то случайно включила отображение автора кода для каждой строки, а теперь нигде не могу найти как запустить это функционал.

Answer (score 1):

Установите расширение gitlens

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens

Updated.

- плюс включить отображение командой "GitLens: Toggle File Blame". Ну и если нужен только автор (а не текст коммита и время, то нужно в настройках по "blame" найти и поправить формат строки отображения. – insolor

Comment: + плюс включить отображение командой "GitLens: Toggle File Blame". Ну и если нужен только автор (а не текст коммита и время, то нужно в настройках по "blame" найти и поправить формат строки отображения.

Comment: @insolor обновил ответ упомянул автора спс